# Predicting next numbers in sequence Keras - Python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm new to python and neural networks. I have a simple network written in Keras that can predict the next number in a linear sequence:

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

data = [[i for i in range(6)]];
data = np.array(data, dtype=int);
target = [[i for i in range(10, 16)]];
target = np.array(target, dtype=int);

model = Sequential();
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(1));
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy']);
model.summary();
for i in range (10000):
    dataIterator = 0;
    for targetValue in target:
        model.train_on_batch(data[dataIterator], targetValue)
        dataIterator = dataIterator + 1;

predict = model.predict([28]);
print(predict);
```

Gives me output:

```
[[38.0199]]
```

And that is to be expected. I'm not sure if my code has some stupid errors in it and would appreciate any feedback and explanations. I used Dense because I'm not sure what LSTM exacly does. Another thing is that my model requires input to have 2 dimensions when it's specified:

```
input_dim=1
```

I don't understand why. Next, I would like to create a network that can predict the next numbers in a sequence like [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]. This one doesn't.

Note that this is my first program written in Python and first use of neural networks :). Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**

According to tip of using scale i came up with something like this:

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from pandas import Series
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = [[i for i in range (1,30)]];
data = np.array(data, dtype=int);
target = np.power(data, 2);
target = np.array(target, dtype=int);
target = target.reshape((len(target[0]), 1))
data = data.reshape((len(data[0]), 1))

scale = StandardScaler()

dataTest = [[i for i in range (2,4)]];
dataTest = np.array(dataTest, dtype=int);
dataTest = dataTest.reshape((len(dataTest[0]), 1))

model = Sequential();
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(1));
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer = 'adam');
model.fit(scale.fit_transform(data), target, batch_size=1, epochs=200, verbose=1)

print(model.predict(scale.transform(dataTest)));
```

Despite this predictions are way off ideal. For given test data, output:

```
[[27.616932]
 [28.265278]]
```

I'm out of ideas at the moment :(. Not feeling it at all.

Answer (score 8):

> And that is to be expected. I'm not sure if my code has some stupid
>   errors in it, would appreciate any feedback and explanations. I used
>   Dense because im not sure what LSTM exactly does.

`LSTM`, which stands for **Long-short term memory**, are a special kind of `RNN`, capable of learning long-term dependencies. Also, its use mainly `sequential processing` over time. For instance, you can use `LSTM` when you want to predict the *Google Stock prices*.

Since you have to predict next numbers in sequence like `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]` that's means it's a **regression** learning system model, which belongs to *supervised* learning. When you're using `regression` models, there is no `accuracy`. The accuracy from *regression* models it's called `COD` or `Coefficient of determination` or [R squared score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).

The `metric` that you use- `metrics=['accuracy']` corresponds to a **classification** problem. If you want to do **regression**, remove `metrics=['accuracy']`. That is, just use

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'mean_absolute_error')
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, i changed code according to what you said, changes looks like that:


   `data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]];`
   `data = np.array(data, dtype=int);`
   `target = [[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]];`
   `target = np.array(target, dtype=int);`
    `...`
    `model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer = 'adam');`
    `...`

and predicts as goes:

    `1=[[-3.0016935]]`
    `2=[[3.9975564]]`
    `3=[[10.996807]]`
    `4=[[17.996058]]`
    `5=[[24.995306]]`
    `6=[[31.994558]]`
    `7=[[38.99381]]`

Not sure what is wrong here :(

Comment: You need to use more data and don't forget about scaling.

Comment: More data sounds logical but what scaling do you have in mind? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, im completly new in Python and Keras.

Comment: @ElKrystiano, have a look to StandardScaler.